# COM interface properties work with Visual Basic 2010, but not C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

I'm working with a proprietary chemical process simulator by AspenTech.  I will reference it in the description below in case anyone is familiar with it, but I don't think it is the root of this issue.  I've been programing for Linux for a long time, but I'm pretty new to Windows programming.

This is all done in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, so Visual Basic 2010 and C# 2010.

I have a library that interacts with Aspen+ and Aspen Custom Modeler 7.3.  Both simulators expose a very similar COM interface I use to interact with them.  My library was originally written in Visual Basic, but we found C# more convenient, so I ported the library to C#.  It works fine with Aspen+, but ACM behaves strangely.  It seems that I can call functions on the ACM COM interface, but I always get the wrong value back when I request a property in C#.  Below is a simple program in Visual Basic that works fine:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim o_acm
    o_acm = CreateObject("ACM Application")
    o_acm.OpenDocument("C:\Users\me\Documents\TestSim.acmf")
    Dim o_sim = o_acm.Simulation
    Dim o_flow = o_sim.Flowsheet
    Dim o_block = o_flow.resolve("ADS2.A1")
    Console.WriteLine(o_block.Value)
End Sub
```

This works fine.  However, exactly the same program in C#:

```
class ACMCSTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    AspenCustomModelerLibrary.AspenCustomModeler o_acm = new AspenCustomModelerLibrary.AspenCustomModeler();
    o_acm.OpenDocument("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\TestSim.acmf");
    dynamic o_sim = o_acm.Simulation;
    dynamic o_flow = o_sim.Flowsheet;
    dynamic o_block = o_sim.resolve("ADS2.A1");
    Console.WriteLine(o_block.Value);
    }
}
```

pulls the wrong object at o_acm.Simulation.  Weirdly, exactly which property I get back incorrectly varies between the library and the test program.  In VB I correctly get back a COM object.  In the C# library .Simulation gives me a string (which is the correct value for a different property, .AppName).  The C# test program, I get back an AspenCustomModelerLibrary.AspenCustomModeler, which could be the value for either of two properties: .Parent or .Application.

The takeaway is that .OpenDocument (a function) works, but all the properties return the wrong property value.

Right now I'm working around this by having a separate Visual Basic wrapper for ACM in the C# library.  Which works, but it awful.

Any idea how I can actually get the COM interface to work correctly with C#?

Comment: Hello, could you please try if the following change fixes your issue?

Comment: Sorry, posted previous comment by mistake. Could you please verify if changing the first line for the following couple of lines fixes your issue?
`Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ACM Application");
 dynamic o_acm = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);`
The reason I'm suggesting the change is that `GetTypeFromProgID()` + 'CreateInstance()' is the equivalent to VB's `CreateObject()` so using it will be more in tune to your VB version  (the static AspenCustomModeler type may actually differ from the type returned by  `CreateObject()`)

Comment: Your vb.net code is purely late-bound.  Your C# is a mix.  Maybe the early-bound code path in the COM server is broken.

Comment: sgorozco's answer above is correct.  Using GetTypeFromProgID solved my problem.  I had looked around for that call before but had failed to find it.
Thanks a log sgorozco!

Comment: Before you get a bad taste in your mouth for Windows programming, CreateObject() is no longer typical, and is mainly (not entirely, but mostly) just a hold-over from the old vb6 days. Almost the only time you should ever need it is for using old components originally written for vb6.